# Display a text insde input text with Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, typeahead, bloodhound, bootstrap-tags-input

i've looking for a tags plugin frontend, and i found an awesome library called **[Bootstrap Tags Input](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput)** and they are have a lot of **[example](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)** but i've problem when i trying to show the **tags.text** as a **text** and the **tags.id** as a **value** for input, which is my JSON data like this:

```
[{"id":3,"text":"aut"},{"id":6,"text":"aut"}]
```

and my **Javascript** so far is look like:

```
var tags = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'api/v1/tags/%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

tags.initialize();

$('#tags').tagsinput({

    typeheadjs: {
      name: 'tags',
      displayKey: 'text',
      valueKey: 'id',
      source: tags.ttAdapter()
    }
});
```

i've trying to use **itemValue** and **itemText** Option, but if i set that options in my javascript function, the users cant add a new tag. Is that possible if i show the text on the input form without a both option that?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem